# PHP session auto-destroyed

Tags: php, ajax, session

I'm getting a strange problem related to `PHP session`:

When I can create a session in `login.php` file, it works perfectly fine all the time.

But when I create a session in a `POST` call to my backend php page via `Ajax call`. Sometime session auto-destroyed on page refresh and some time it didn't.

Can anyone give a hint, what can be the issue ?

Comment: is the timeout reached?

Comment: @Raptor I refresh page, in a short time... mostly less than 1 min.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid regenerating your session ID "session_regenerate_id()" during you ajax call. Which framework you are using ? I personally faced same issue with Code Ignitor.

Answer (score -1):

Use firebug to check if session cookie exists. Check that you are using session_start in php scripts. session_start must be first sentence of script